# python pandas row startswith one letter one number wildcard

Tags: python, regex, pandas, startswith

Trying to filter out rows in my data, I need to match the first letter `N` followed by a number, then drop rows that don't match this criteria.

I've tried multiple regex combinations from stackoverflow but they don't seem to work properly

```
new = new.loc[new['call_x'].str.startswith("^[N]{1}[0-9]+")]

Example data
N902AG #keep
N917GA #keep
N918PD #keep
N919PD #keep
N930EN #keep
N940CL #keep
N976TR #keep
N98AW #keep
NAX6700 #drop
NAX7019 #drop
NKS1028 #drop
NKS171 #drop
NKS174 #drop
NKS197 #drop
```

Comment: I dont think `str.startswith` accepts regex. You should use `re` package instead: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Seem like you are using pandas. Adding `pandas` tag really matters.

Comment: @gzc thanks gzc, oversight on my part, that's been added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [pandas.Series.str.contains](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) to match regexp.

```
df = df.loc[df['a'].str.contains('^N[0-9]+')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas `str.startswith` doesn't accept regex. You want `str.match`.
Try this:

```
df[df.Example.str.match('^N\d+')]
```

`str.contains` is similar but looks for matches anywhere in the string, not just the start.

Comment: While this piece of code may answer the question, it is better to include a description of what the problem was, and how your code will tackle the given problem. For the future, here is some information, [how to crack a awesome answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on Stack Overflow.